# pause() and sigsuspend() when used in inter-process communication

Tags: c, linux, signals

Suppose there are two processes, a parent and a child, which use the signal for synchronization. In the parent process, the function used to sync with child acts as below.

```
WAIT_CHILD(){
  while(sigflag == 0){ //sigflag will be set to 1 in a signal handler in the child process
    sigsuspend(&zeromask); //No signal is in the mask set
  }

  //do sth....
}
```

My question is can we use `pause()` to replace the `sigsuspend(&zeromask)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The posted code is only race-condition-free if the prevailing signal mask is blocking the signal that is sent by the child, and if that is the case then, since `pause()` will not change the signal mask, it would block forever.

The reason that the signal must be initially blocked is that otherwise, a signal could arrive in between the test `sigflag == 0` and the `sigsuspend()`, which means the process would have missed the signal and get stuck.